# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting this error while running my spring application

```
{"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52183:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\Downloads\springapi\target\classes;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.11.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.11.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.2\lombok-1.16.2.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.11\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.9.3\jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.9\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.10.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.1.4.Final\hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.2.3.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar" com.springapplication.springapi.SpringapiApplication

          .   ____          _            __ _ _
         /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
        ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
         \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
          '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
         =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
         :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.9.RELEASE)

        2019-10-03 11:25:02.431  INFO 668 --- [           main] c.s.springapi.SpringapiApplication       : Starting SpringapiApplication on Chinecherem with PID 668 (C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\Downloads\springapi\target\classes started by ChinecheremAugustina in C:\Users\ChinecheremAugustina\Downloads\springapi)
        2019-10-03 11:25:02.431  INFO 668 --- [           main] c.s.springapi.SpringapiApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
        2019-10-03 11:25:03.024 ERROR 668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at com.springapplication.springapi.SpringapiApplication.main(SpringapiApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:156) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:149) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:137) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:269) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:262) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:251) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:171) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:145) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            ... 17 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            ... 39 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            ... 43 common frames omitted

        2019-10-03 11:25:03.024  WARN 668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:604) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:866) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:854) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:841) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:792) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at com.springapplication.springapi.SpringapiApplication.main(SpringapiApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
            ... 21 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            ... 25 common frames omitted


        Process finished with exit code 1
        }
    {
```

my application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=englishlang

    #spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialet= org.hibernate.dialect.Mysql5Dialect

    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update}
```

my pom.xml

```
    {
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.springapplication</groupId>
        <artifactId>springapi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>springapi</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven/</url>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <!--            <version>1.12.6</version>-->
                <version>1.16.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
                <version>8.0.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: you don't need `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` you can remove them

Comment: I am still getting the same error after removing hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager

Answer (score 0):

Her is what I did to remove this error,

I simply removed the unwanted hibernate properties and booted the application and working as expected.

my POM XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.SpringDataJpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDataJpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringDataJpa</name>
    <description>SpringDataJpawith basic example application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

MY Application.properties file:

```
server.port=8097
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about the reason but changing the version worked for me.

from

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```